# Cakephp URL Parameters

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a Cakephp 2.1 app.

My function is declared:

```
public function ajaxOfferingDelete($descipline_name = -1, $field_id = -1)
{
    $this->layout = 'empty';

    //output code
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Enter this into the URL works fine:

```
localhost/lessonshark/teachers/ajaxOfferingDelete/
```

The above outputs hello but the bottom gives me nothing:

```
 localhost/lessonshark/teachers/ajaxOfferingDelete/1/137
```

Why is this happening? It was working before.

Comment: the page just goes white and i can't even have debug set

Comment: How are your routes set up? Are you passing the parameters correctly to the action?

Comment: use `pr($this->request->params);die;` or print both the arguments followed by `die` statement in your `ajaxOfferingDelete()` method. and check the output.

Comment: no still white, its like the page can't be routed properly - how should i set up the routes

Comment: change the debug value from 0 to 2. Here `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in app/Config/core.php and check.

Comment: @chris: please provide your routes for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created 'empty' layout? If you did, you must have in it:

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```